# Is this statement about roots of polynomials well-known?

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, roots, convex-hulls

Here is the statement :

> Let $P$ be a non constant polynomial of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ which has at least two distinct roots. If $P''$ divides $P$ hence all the roots of $P$ belong to the same (real) line.

The ingredients used are : $P$ has in fact only simple roots, the Gauss-Lucas theorem and the extreme points of a convex set.

It seems slightly similar to Jensen's theorem.

I was wondering if it was a well-known fact about the roots of a non constant complex polynomial ? If so, are there any references about it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1454206/305862 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2839020/305862

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you ! Do we have something interesting about the second part !?

Comment: What are you calling "the second part" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie the fact that all the roots of $P$ belong to the same line.

Comment: According to the answer given to the second reference I gave, it is the line joining roots $a$ and $b$... Strange formulation but not contradictory...

Comment: Warning: A **complex line** is a plan respect to $\mathbb R$ (dimensión $1$ **over $\mathbb C$ but $2$ over  $\mathbb R$**.

Comment: @Piquito Indeed you are right !

Comment: @JeanMarie Ok it seems easier than using theorems like Gauss-Lucas or extreme points in a convex set...

Comment: @Maman The answer that I previously posted was wrong, so I removed it. The mistake was actually in my other [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2839038/291201) it relied upon, which I fixed since. In summary, your $P$ has two distinct roots, and the conclusion there is that it must have all distinct roots (otherwise it would have to be a perfect power). It is not immediately obvious how/whether that helps with your question here, but at least the question makes a lot more sense now. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for clarifying the reasoning ! That means that $P$ will be of the form $c\prod (x-\lambda_i)$. And for the roots to be on the same (real) line, how would we conclude ? Maybe it is a this point that we have to use Gauss-Lucas theorem or something like that ?

Comment: @Maman Right, it should work along that line, though I was looking/hoping for a more direct and possibly constructive proof, which I still believe must exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2839038/291201) proves that any polynomial of degree $\,n\ge 3\,$ which satisfies $\,P''(x) \mid P(x)\,$ and has at least two distinct roots must have all $\,n\,$ roots distinct.

Let $\,P(x) = \lambda(x-a)(x-b)P''(x)\,$ with $\,a \ne b\,$ and $\,c_i \big|_{i=1,2,\dots,n-2}\,$ the roots of $\,P''\,$, all distinct and different from $\,a, b\,$. If $\,d_j \big|_{j=1,2,\dots,k \,\le\,n-2}\,$ are the [extreme points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) of the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) $\,C_{P''} =\text{Conv}(c_i)\,$ then $\,\text{Conv}(d_i) = C_{P''}\,$ by the [Krein–Milman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem#Statement).

Let $\,C_{P'}\,$ be the convex hull of the roots of $\,P'\,$, and $\,C_P = \text{Conv}(a, b, c_i)\,$, then $\,C_{P''} \subseteq C_{P'} \subseteq C_P\,$ by the [Gauss-Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem#Formal_statement). Root $\,d_1\,$ of $\,P'' \mid P\,$ is in both $\,C_P\,$ and $\,C_{P''}\,$, so it must be in $\,C_{P'}\,$. However, $\,d_1\,$ cannot be an extreme point of $\,C_{P'}\,$ since those are among the roots of $\,P'\,$, and $\,P'\,$ has no roots in common with $\,P\,$ because all roots are simple. Therefore $\,d_1\,$ cannot be an extreme point of $\,C_P\,$, either, since an extreme point of a convex set is an extreme point of any convex subset that contains it.

By symmetry, none of the $\,d_j\,$ can be extreme points of $\,C_P\,$, either. Since $\,C_P\,$ contains $\,a,b\,$ and, by convexity, the entire segment $\,\overline{ab}\,$, it follows that the only extreme points are $\,a,b\,$, and all other roots $\,c_i\,$ must lie within segment $\,\overline{ab}\,$.

Comment: As I just commented on the linked answer, the claim at the top is false, and $P(x) = x^3 - x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @RaviFernando Thanks for catching that. Revised and reworked.

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know if there are any references about this statement ?

Comment: @Maman I did run a cursory search on polynomials with collinear roots, but came up empty. The case of the cubic was answered on MSE under [When are the roots of a polynomial of degree 3 aligned?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4150914/when-are-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-of-degree-3-aligned), but I didn't find much about the general case. Polynomials with $\,P'' \mid P\,$ form just a small subset of those with all roots on a line. For example, in the case of a cubic, $\,P'' \mid P\,$ iff one root is the midpoint of the others.

Comment: @Maman On second thought, polynomials with collinear roots may not be "interesting" enough to merit much study on their own, since they directly [relate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4461010/291201) to polynomials with all-real roots and their ranges, which is a more general and better studied problem.

Comment: @dxiv Maybe you'll find that claim interesting. If we suppose that the two distinct roots of $P$ are real then under the same conditions, we can deduce that all the roots of $P$ are in fact real (and simple) !

Comment: @Maman Right. Another direct consequence is that, if $\,P\,$ is a *real* polynomial with distinct roots on a line, then that line must be either the real axis or parallel to the imaginary axis. This follows because the roots of $\,P^{(n-2)}\,$ must be on the same line, and the roots of a quadratic with real coefficients are either real or complex conjugates (and, in fact, it's enough for the leading three coefficients of $\,P\,$ to be real).